# oracle view create error ora-00933

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE VIEW PEGADATA.LIST_WORKLIST_WB_ITEMS AS
SELECT pxRefObjectInsName AS CASEID, pyAssignmentStatus AS STATUS, pxCreateDateTime AS CREATEDATETIME, pxAssignedOperatorID AS ASSIGNEDTO, pxGoalTime AS GOALTIME, pxDeadlineTime AS DEADLINETIME, pxGoalExecute AS GOALEXECUTETIME, pxDeadlineExecute AS DEADLINEEXECUTETIME, pxRefObjectClass AS REFERENCEDOBJCLASS, pxApplication AS APPLICATIONNAME, pyFlowType AS FLOWTYPE, pzInsKey AS INSTANCEHANDLEKEY, pxWorkGroup AS WORKGROUP, pxAssignedUserName AS ASSIGNEDUSERNAME
FROM PEGADATA.pc_assign_worklist
UNION
SELECT pxRefObjectInsName AS CASEID, pyAssignmentStatus AS STATUS, pxCreateDateTime AS CREATEDATETIME, pxAssignedOperatorID AS ASSIGNEDTO, pxGoalTime AS GOALTIME, pxDeadlineTime AS DEADLINETIME, pxGoalExecute AS GOALEXECUTETIME, pxDeadlineExecute AS DEADLINEEXECUTETIME, pxRefObjectClass AS REFERENCEDOBJCLASS, pxApplication AS APPLICATIONNAME, pyFlowType AS FLOWTYPE, pzInsKey AS INSTANCEHANDLEKEY, pxWorkGroup AS WORKGROUP, DA.pyLabel AS ASSIGNEDUSERNAME
FROM PEGADATA.pc_assign_workbasket, PEGADATA.pr_data_admin AS DA WHERE INNER JOIN PEGADATA.pc_assign_workbasket ON pxAssignedOperatorID = DA.pyWorkBasket;
```

I get error:

> -ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: You can't use `AS` when defining a table alias; but what is the `WHERE INNER JOIN` part supposed to be doing? Go back and look at the syntax diagrams again; and also don't mix old-style syntax (multiple comma-separated tables) with newer join syntax, even when ou have the individual parts right - preferably only use the newer `JOIN ... ON` style.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need:

```
CREATE VIEW PEGADATA.LIST_WORKLIST_WB_ITEMS AS
    SELECT pxRefObjectInsName AS CASEID,
           pyAssignmentStatus AS STATUS,
           pxCreateDateTime AS CREATEDATETIME,
           pxAssignedOperatorID AS ASSIGNEDTO,
           pxGoalTime AS GOALTIME,
           pxDeadlineTime AS DEADLINETIME,
           pxGoalExecute AS GOALEXECUTETIME,
           pxDeadlineExecute AS DEADLINEEXECUTETIME,
           pxRefObjectClass AS REFERENCEDOBJCLASS,
           pxApplication AS APPLICATIONNAME,
           pyFlowType AS FLOWTYPE,
           pzInsKey AS INSTANCEHANDLEKEY,
           pxWorkGroup AS WORKGROUP,
           pxAssignedUserName AS ASSIGNEDUSERNAME
      FROM PEGADATA.pc_assign_worklist
    UNION
    SELECT pxRefObjectInsName AS CASEID,
           pyAssignmentStatus AS STATUS,
           pxCreateDateTime AS CREATEDATETIME,
           pxAssignedOperatorID AS ASSIGNEDTO,
           pxGoalTime AS GOALTIME,
           pxDeadlineTime AS DEADLINETIME,
           pxGoalExecute AS GOALEXECUTETIME,
           pxDeadlineExecute AS DEADLINEEXECUTETIME,
           pxRefObjectClass AS REFERENCEDOBJCLASS,
           pxApplication AS APPLICATIONNAME,
           pyFlowType AS FLOWTYPE,
           pzInsKey AS INSTANCEHANDLEKEY,
           pxWorkGroup AS WORKGROUP,
           DA.pyLabel AS ASSIGNEDUSERNAME
      FROM PEGADATA.pr_data_admin DA
        INNER JOIN
           PEGADATA.pc_assign_workbasket ON pxAssignedOperatorID = DA.pyWorkBasket;
```